# Blueprint bundle is waiting for dependencies [(&(component=netty4-http)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))]

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, netty4

I have the following camel context that builds and installs on karaf ok, at least no errors.

Receives Current Grade from Camu
        
        
            The request raw from bpms
        
        
            {{api.key}}

The problem is

```
is waiting for dependencies [(&(component=netty4-http)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))]
```

I have installed the camel-http feature and the camel-nett4 feature with no impact. Thge pom is ok with the nett4 dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-netty4-http</artifactId>
      <version>2.21.0.fuse-730078-redhat-00001</version>
    </dependency>
```

what do I try next

Answer (score 1):

is waiting for dependencies - means that your application waiting for service at apache karaf. at this case netty4-http you have to re